# Cannot compact realm. Realm.getInstance crashes my app on LG G5

Tags: android, database, file, realm

I get this error when trying to run the following REALM code. Why is this happening?

Code:

```
  public static void deleteRealm(Context context) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(PSApplicationClass.Config);
    try {
        Log.i("", "realm start");
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.delete(Destination.class);
                realm.delete(TripStep.class);
                realm.delete(TripStop.class);
                realm.delete(Route.class);
                realm.delete(RealmLocation.class);
                realm.delete(PSTrip.class);
                realm.delete(PSUser.class);
                realm.delete(UserVehicle.class);
                realm.delete(Vehicle.class);
                realm.delete(MileageRates.class);
                realm.delete(PSUserActivityMonth.class);
                realm.delete(PSUserActivityWeek.class);
                realm.delete(PSUserActivityYear.class);
                realm.delete(Activity.class);
                realm.delete(PSTripsStats.class);
            }
        });
        realm.close();
        RealmManager.closeInstance();
        try {
            boolean compact = Realm.compactRealm(PSApplicationClass.Config);
            Log.i("", "GLOBAL realm end: " + compact);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Utils.appendLog("Error trying to compact realm","E", Constants.OTHER);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("", "realm continue initTrip error trying to add to realm:" + e.getMessage());
        if (realm.isInTransaction()) {
            realm.cancelTransaction();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
01-02 11:12:40.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18999): Process: nl.hgrams.passenger, PID: 18999
01-02 11:12:40.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18999): io.realm.exceptions.RealmFileException: Unable to open a realm at path '/data/data/nl.hgrams.passenger/files/myrealm.realm.management': make_dir() failed: No such file or directory. (make_dir() failed: No such file or directory) (/data/data/nl.hgrams.passenger/files/myrealm.realm.management) in /home/cc/repo/realm/release/realm/realm-library/src/main/cpp/io_realm_internal_SharedRealm.cpp line 217 Kind: ACCESS_ERROR.
01-02 11:12:40.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18999):    at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.nativeGetSharedRealm(Native Method)
01-02 11:12:40.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18999):    at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.<init>(SharedRealm.java:192)
01-02 11:12:40.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18999):    at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.getInstance(SharedRealm.java:240)
01-02 11:12:40.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18999):    at io.realm.internal.SharedRealm.getInstance(SharedRealm.java:208)
01-02 11:12:40.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18999):    at io.realm.RealmCache.doCreateRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:297)
01-02 11:12:40.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18999):    at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:283)
01-02 11:12:40.352: E/AndroidRuntime(18999):    at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:291)
```

This happens at `Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(PSApplicationClass.Config);`

This does not happen on a Le Eco Le 2 Pro , or a Nexus 5, but it does happen on my LG G5. Am I doing something wrong with the way I'm compacting? (The compact code is not yet reached here, I so I don't see how this might be possible.

Comment: According to logs, `No such file or directory`. Check `/data/data` is present or not.

Comment: can you post PSApplicationClass.Config code

Comment: ` Config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().name("myrealm.realm").schemaVersion(3).deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build();`

Comment: hwo can I check if that file exists on my phone, from the terminal?

Comment: The exception meant that you were somewhere deleting Realm's files while the Realm was open.

Comment: Understood this after a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more testing and trial and error, I found the issue. on Logout, I was removing the context of the data dir. so for phones with API > N would crash:

```
   int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        FileUtils.deleteQuietly(context.getDataDir());
    }
```